# In Red Dwarf episode 'Ouroboros', how does Dave Lister go back in time?

Tags: red-dwarf

In the Red Dwarf episode Ouroboros, Dave Lister must return to the Aigburth Arms to plant himself there as a baby (and therefore to ensure, due to the infinite loop in time, humanity will never truly die out)

How did he go back in time? I would have thought this was too large plot device simply to ignore.

My first thought is that he may have used the off photographic chemicals that they had in Timeslides, but I have no memory of this ever having been stated, or that the photographic chemicals survived the multiple time rewrites the episode used.

Was it ever stated, or discussed, how Lister did return to 2155?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Judging from the FX used, which are the same as in *Tikka to Ride*, they use the time machine from the Gemini 12, originally seen in *Out of Time*.  The time drive shows up in several episodes.

Comment: I guess that was only two episodes previous. Still, I think the answer lies on an edit room floor somewhere.

Comment: It's possible, since the episode already ran long.  I was reading that it was the 2nd episode in a row that had to be aired without opening credits, so I'm sure they had already cut everything they could.  Also, from a writer's point of view, they had already had a long discussion about going back to the Gemini 12 to get the time drive in _Tikka to Ride_, so they probably felt that it wasn't necessary to revisit that plot point.